# Problem with database in vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net

I have a problem with the database preview

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Database1DataSet.EmployeDB' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.EmployeDBTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database1DataSet.EmployeDB)
    If ComboBox1.Text = Nothing Then
        Try
            Me.EmployeDBTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database1DataSet.EmployeDB)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If First_NameTextBox.Text = Nothing OrElse
        Last_NameTextBox.Text = Nothing OrElse
        Middle_NameTextBox.Text = Nothing OrElse
        GenderTextBox.Text = Nothing OrElse
        ID__TextBox.Text = Nothing OrElse
        Telephone__TextBox.Text = Nothing Then
        MsgBox("All Fields are Required", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")

    ElseIf GenderTextBox.Text <> "M" And
            GenderTextBox.Text <> "F" And
            GenderTextBox.Text <> "m" And
            GenderTextBox.Text <> "f" Then
        MsgBox("Gender Input Is only M and F.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")

    Else Try
            Me.Validate()
            Me.EmployeDBBindingSource.EndEdit()
            Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Database1DataSet)
            EmployeDBBindingSource.AddNew()
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved.", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            First_NameTextBox.Select()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Select Case MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete the data?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Info")
        Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
            Try
                ComboBox1.Text = ""
                First_NameTextBox.Clear()
                Last_NameTextBox.Clear()
                Middle_NameTextBox.Clear()
                Telephone__TextBox.Clear()
                ID__TextBox.Clear()
                GenderTextBox.Clear()
                EmployeDBBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
                Me.Validate()
                Me.EmployeDBBindingSource.EndEdit()
                Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Database1DataSet)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Error")
            End Try
        Case MsgBoxResult.No
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    ComboBox1.Text = ""
    First_NameTextBox.Clear()
    Last_NameTextBox.Clear()
    Middle_NameTextBox.Clear()
    Telephone__TextBox.Clear()
    ID__TextBox.Clear()
    GenderTextBox.Clear()
    Me.EmployeDBTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database1DataSet.EmployeDB)
    Me.Validate()
    Me.EmployeDBBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Database1DataSet)
    EmployeDBBindingSource.AddNew()
End Sub

End Class
```

my problem is how i can eliminate the "-1" sign in the ID and the starting in ID is almost 1000 even though it is the first data(I made data before but i delete it), also I don't know the very first "save" doesnt save data but rather make a blank space, the second save only saves and show the data in the right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ID field is autoincremental, then you will never get the same ID again even if one is deleted.

Sorry for the other questions but I don't get them